# AngularJS routes add any special characters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

the problem: When I just type http://localhost:53379 I'm redirected to http://localhost:53379/#/ . Where come from the /#/ ?

```
angular
        .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngStorage'])
        .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            debugger;
            $routeProvider.when('/:module/:task/:id/:menu/:action', { templateUrl: 'app/blank.html', controller: PagesCtrl });
            $routeProvider.when('/:module/:task/:id/:menu', { templateUrl: 'app/blank.html', controller: PagesCtrl });
            $routeProvider.when('/:module/:task/:id', { templateUrl: 'app/blank.html', controller: PagesCtrl });
            $routeProvider.when('/:module/:task', { templateUrl: 'app/blank.html', controller: PagesCtrl });
            $routeProvider.when('/:module', { templateUrl: 'app/blank.html', controller: PagesCtrl });
            $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'app/start.html' });
            $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, AngularJS will route URLs with a hashtag.

For example:

```
http://domain.com/#/home
http://domain.com/#/about
```

You can very easy remove the hashtag from the URL by setting html5Mode to true in your config:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

So in your code it will be:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngStorage'])
       .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            debugger;
            $routeProvider.when('/:module/:task/:id/:menu/:action', { templateUrl: 'app/blank.html', controller: PagesCtrl });
            $routeProvider.when('/:module/:task/:id/:menu', { templateUrl: 'app/blank.html', controller: PagesCtrl });
            $routeProvider.when('/:module/:task/:id', { templateUrl: 'app/blank.html', controller: PagesCtrl });
            $routeProvider.when('/:module/:task', { templateUrl: 'app/blank.html', controller: PagesCtrl });
            $routeProvider.when('/:module', { templateUrl: 'app/blank.html', controller: PagesCtrl });
            $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'app/start.html' });
            $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        }
    ]);
```

Just after that you have to make sure that your backed will redirect all requests to your home page if you are doing "Single Page App"

Comment: ok.. welcome, please see the entire document  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location , I think it is very useful for you

Comment: Ok, thank you once again, already i am waste 2 or 3 hours for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`#` is by default set for routing in angular unless you set the following history api pushstate in the config:

```
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

basically angular uses hash change for routing by default.